# Authenticating FreeRadius request with Atlassian Crowd

Tags: freeradius, atlassian-crowd

I want to authenticate users using Atlassian Crowd from FreeRADIUS and I've been unable to find a plugin or particularly good examples of how this might be done. Specifically in trying to implement the authorize and authenticate portions using an `rlm_python` script isn't terribly clear. Is there a more complex example where a RESTful backend is used to authenticate without needing to know the password in the `authorize` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some experimentation I created a plugin using [python-crowd](https://github.com/pycontribs/python-crowd). You need to add a new Auth-Type to the `authorize` file that I called `CROWD` and add python as the authenticator and the authorize section of that file. In `mod-configs/python` make sure to set the module name and enable authorize and authenticate function calls.

#### crowdplugin.py

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import radiusd
import crowd

cs = None
app_url = ''
app_user = ''
app_pass = ''

def instantiate(p):
  global cs
  cs = crowd.CrowdServer(app_url, app_user, app_pass)

def authorize(p):
  reply = None
  config = None
  result = radiusd.RLM_MODULE_NOTFOUND

  values = dict(p)
  username = values['User-Name']
  success = cs.get_user(username)
  if success:
     config = ( ( 'Auth-Type', 'crowd' ), )
     result = radiusd.RLM_MODULE_OK
  return ( result, reply, config )

def authenticate(p):
  reply = None
  config = None
  result = radiusd.RLM_MODULE_REJECT

  values = dict(p)
  username = values['User-Name']
  password = values['User-Password']
  success = cs.auth_user(username, password)
  if success:
     reply = ( ( 'Reply-Message', 'Welcome!'), )
     result = radiusd.RLM_MODULE_OK
  return ( result, reply, config )
```